# Inputting key events to a running console application from winform

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, winforms, cmd

I am in the process of creating a windows forms application using C#, for this I needed to use an external application that is build with C++ and is a console application. So I created the process and passed the arguments for the main methods and everything seems to work perfectly fine though the only issue here is that to end the process the already built application requires you to "hit ENTER to stop" and this I can't seem to get my head around. How can I input ENTER to this process that I have created from the main WinForms app that I am building.
PS: the app that I am using was downloaded from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56882/MP-Sound-Recording-Tool)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are asking how to write a WinForm application to control the Winform application provided in your referenced CodeProject article and the CP WinForm itself controls a console application?   If so, why not just modify the WinForm code you can downloaded from CP?

Comment: I'm sorry I think I didn't explain myself clearly no I want to control the C++ application from within that CodeProject article [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15588/Sound-recording-and-encoding-in-MP3-format)